# getValidUnsentAddresses() if-else condition not functioning as intended

Tags: java, exception, if-statement, jakarta-mail

I'm working on an mailing app. The app can receive multiple recipient addresses. Once the "Send" button is pressed, a single message is sent containing multiple recipient addresses. Of course, by having this kind of system, there would be an SendFailedException if at least one of the addresses is invalid. Naturally, I would catch this and exception and try to work around with it. Here's my code so far:

```
catch (SendFailedException e)
        {   try 
            {
                System.out.println(e.getValidUnsentAddresses()!=null);
                if (e.getValidUnsentAddresses()!=null) //with valid unsent addresses
                {
                    String invalid = new String();
                    String valid = new String();
                    for (int i=0; i<e.getInvalidAddresses().length; i++)
                    {
                        invalid = invalid + e.getInvalidAddresses()[i].toString();
                        if (i+1<e.getInvalidAddresses().length)
                        {
                            invalid = invalid + ", ";
                        }
                    }

                    for (int i=0; i<e.getValidUnsentAddresses().length; i++)
                    {
                        valid = valid + e.getValidUnsentAddresses()[i].toString();
                        if (i+1<e.getValidUnsentAddresses().length)
                        {
                            valid = valid + ", ";
                        }
                    }

                    int choice = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, invalid +  " are invalid addresses. Send mail to valid addresses?", "Information", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, null, "No");
                    if (choice==0)
                    {
                        transport.sendMessage(message, e.getValidUnsentAddresses());
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sent message to " + valid + ".", "Information", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    }
                }

                else //no valid unsent addresses
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "All email addresses are invalid.", "Information", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
            }     

            catch(MessagingException e2)
            { e2.printStackTrace(); }

        }
```

Loop to add recipient addresses to message:

```
for (int i=0; i<listModel.getSize(); i++) //listModel is of DefaultListModel Class
{   
    message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress((String)listModel.getElementAt(i)));
}
```

Then at the end:

```
properties = System.getProperties();
session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
transport.connect(host, textEmail.getText(), new String(pwdPassword.getPassword()));
transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients()); // <----this part throws the SendFailedException
transport.close();
```

Now onto the problem. You could see that there's an if-else statement immediately inside the catch block. I wanted to check whether there were any valid unsent addresses in the recipients. This way I can know if there are only invalid addresses in the recipients (as there are no valid sent addresses since the message fails to send because of the exception).

I've run some tests on the system. It works fine if all addresses are valid, however, when a single invalid address is included, a minor problem appears. If I were to put only invalid addresses in the recipients, it is supposed to go to the "else" part, but instead it always ends up in the "if" part of the statement.

While it is only a minor problem (it's only about prompts), I would still like to know why my condition doesn't work. I might be missing something about the SendFailedException

Answer (score 0):

Try putting all invalid addresses and it should work

If is executed everytime because even if one valid address is there

```
e.getValidUnsentAddresses();
```

will not return null

Comment: that's the problem. If I put all invalid addresses, it doesn't go to the "else" part as intended

Comment: its as simple as `e.getValidUnsentAddresses()` is not coming as null, also you need to put code which has logic of setting this field and getting it etc to enable me to help you

Comment: it's quite long if I placed all the code here. Basically, I have a GUI that allows me to input recipients. By pressing the "Add" button, I can add the email address to a DefaultListModel object. Once the "Send" button is pressed, a method will be called that creates the message itself. Within that method is a loop to extract all the content of the DefaultListModel object and add them as recipients

Comment: just paste that loop where you are dealing with addresses and also where you defined validUnsentAddress

Comment: I editted my question. The validUnsentAddress() method is from SendFailedException Class